# writing correct syntax for update statement with left join

Tags: mysql, sql-update, syntax-error, left-join

I have a code for update statement with left join in it. This code is to update a_status in table a when users insert new data in another table, table b. In short, I want to simultaneously update table a on column a_status, when table b get a new data.

```
UPDATE a
LEFT JOIN b
ON a_id = b_id
SET a_status = 'Process'
WHERE
b_id = a_id;
```

This code works and gave me the result I wanted. But I have to implemented this into another way of writing which use array and MySQL::updateData(). The problem is I am not familiar with using this writing syntax. Can anybody help me on how to write it so that I can use left join or anything that can gives out the result I wanted in the above code. Here is what I did so far:

```
 $arr = array("b"=>array( array('b_id','b_modul','b_tkmsk'), 
        array($_GET['b_id'],$_GET['b_modul'],$_GET['b_tkmsk']),
        ));
  MySQL::insertData($arr);    

$arr = array("a"=>array(array('a_status'),
       array('Proccess'),
       "where a_id = b_id"));

  MySQL::updateData($arr);
```

Comment: An outer join is odd in this context

Comment: @Strawberry do you have any suggestion then because without join I got error..Unknown column 'b_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You are writing code in some language with some library--what are they & where are the tags? And have you read the manual? PS Do you understand the difference between inner join & outer join?